# Jobs says he cracked the TV code - How can Apps successfully integrate into the TV watching experience?

Tags: applications

Apps are out there today with Samsung's Smart TV, AT&T's U-verse has a few, Google 2.0 is coming out soon, etc.. however, most seem like a novelty. Is there a way applications can successfully integrate into the TV watching experience?

Maybe it's something like this > Turn on TV > Dashboard of App icons = TV Guide App, HBO App, CNN App, Facetime App (TV has integrated cam/mic), NFL App, Weather App, Flight Tracker App, Friend Finder App, Slide Show App, Facebook App, Alarm Clock App, PBS App, Yahoo Finance App... you get the idea.

Using iCloud, the TV would sync with your iPhone/iPad. Most likely, the TV would be used for updates/alerts as opposed to data entry since using a TV remote can be cumbersome. And knowing Jobs, it will probably have as few buttons as possible. Each App would have the ability to watch live broadcast or recorded TV with integrated data functionality like through a buttonpress on the remote.

Would this work?

Comment: IMO current solutions aren't that bad (my TV has the same setup you describe, except it requires one extra button press). The problem lies in weaning people off broadcast/cable TV, which feels mindless relative to actually looking for a specific app/ect

Comment: I believe the issue with apps on TVs is not the navigation or app layout. The big issues for me are resolution and controls. I can fit more content on my iPhone than on a large screen TV.  Controlling my TV is also a frustrating task. Traditional remote controls do not work for most apps. Slimmed down keyboards with small track-pads are also not ideal.

Comment: Hi Pixelist, "What do you think of my idea for an Apple TV UI" is not a good question for our site. Please see our [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) - this question is unanswerable in its current form. You could improve it by asking a more specific question than "would this work?".

Comment: I think it's an interesting topic but, yea, not entirely clear what the question is. Anyways, to get an idea of 'apps' on TV, take a look at Roku or Boxee--both have figured out pretty good UIs for app navigation and use. Netflix being the king of remote-based TV apps.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Web TV' discussion has been going for a long time;

Jakob Nielsen's covered it quite well over the years:

Eg: Alertbox for February 1, 1997:

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9702a.html

In terms of the emotional differences of watching TV versus interacting with a PC the search term 'lean forward lean back' finds some useful information.

Comment: Can you summarize some of that review or post some excerpts to prevent link rot?

Comment: I'll not bother this time since the question is closed.  However I'll summarise Nielsen if someone comes back with a better question on 'Interactive TV', which I think would be the modern term for Web TV.

Answer (score 2):

Who says that "cracked the code" refers to being able to run apps on a TV at all?

You also refer to "watch live broadcast or recorded TV". If a TV is truly innovative then those are exactly concepts of the past. A good TV would allow me to watch whatever I want whenever I want.